# HTTPS configuration not working for Elastic Beanstalk node.js application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following the AWS documentation to configure HTTPS for a single instance eb application.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html
Below is my configuration file which I amputting in .ebextensions. Please find it below (I have masked the certificate and Key for security purposes.

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # HTTPS server

      server {
          listen       443;
          server_name  localhost;

          ssl                  on;
          ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

          ssl_session_timeout  5m;

          ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
          ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

          # For enhanced health reporting support, uncomment this block:

          #if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          #    set $year $1;
          #    set $month $2;
          #    set $day $3;
          #    set $hour $4;
          #}
          #access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
          #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

          location / {
              proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
              proxy_set_header   Connection "";
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
          }
      }
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But when I redeploy the application I am able to access the beanstalk URL via http the moment I try with HTTPs I get "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" error. Can anyone help me out here.